# iOS Core data: Fetching more objects than saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am new to Core Data, and I am trying to use it for saving users. However, when I first create a user it inserts the user. This seems to go fine. It is only called once.

```
-(void)insertUser: (User *) user{
    [self userToModel:user];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Unable to save managed object context");
    }
}

-(UserModel *)userToModel:(User *) user{
    UserModel *usermodel = [NSEntityDescription
                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserModel"
                            inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [usermodel setValue:user.username forKey:@"username"];
    [usermodel setValue:user.password forKey:@"password"];
    [usermodel setValue:user.sessionid forKey:@"sessionid"];
    [usermodel setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE] forKey:@"selected"];
    [usermodel setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:user.beta] forKey:@"beta"];

    return usermodel;
}
```

Next, I am fetching the users and it is returning 3 users: 2 exact similar Users, and one nil model.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getUsers{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserModel"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSError *error;
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *usermodels= [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(UserModel *userModel in usermodels){
        User *user = [self userModelToUser:userModel];
        [users addObject:user];
    }
    return users;
}
```

UserModelToUser:

```
-(User *)userModelToUser:(UserModel *)usermodel{
    User *user = [[User alloc]initWithUsername:usermodel.username
                                      Password:usermodel.password
                                     CSRFToken:usermodel.csrftoken
                                     sessionid:usermodel.sessionid
                                          Beta:[usermodel.beta boolValue]
                                      Selected:[usermodel.selected boolValue]];
    return user;
}
```

SelectUser

```
-(void)selectUser: (User *)userToSelect OldUser:(User *)oldSelectedUser{
    UserModel *oldSelectedUserModel = [self userToModel:oldSelectedUser];
    UserModel *newSelectedUsermodel = [self userToModel:userToSelect];
    [oldSelectedUserModel setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE] forKey:@"selected"];
    [newSelectedUsermodel setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE] forKey:@"selected"];

    NSError *saveError;
    if (![context save:&saveError]) {
        NSLog(@"Changing users failed %@", saveError);
    }
}
```

I already tried to reinstall the app to make sure no old users are still saved or anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Set a breakpoint or add an NSLog to `userToModel` - verify that it is only being called once.   Is that method the only place you call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`

Comment: I already did that, and yes it is.

Comment: What do you do in `userModelToUser`?

Comment: I convert my User object to the Database user model

Comment: Can you show the code?  If `userToModel` is only called once then the problem isn't in the code shown here

Comment: I sort of figured it out. It has to do with me calling the above selectUser method

Comment: My I suggest that instead of converting `UserModel`s to `User`s you just use the one class.